# $3^a=5^b=15^c$, express $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $$3^a=5^b=15^c$$, express $c$ in terms of $a$ and $b$.

Can anyone give me some hints on this question? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$3^a=5^b=15^c=k$$

$$3=k^{\frac 1a}$$

$$5=k^{\frac 1b}$$

$$15=k^{\frac 1c}$$

Now $$3 \cdot 5 = 15$$

$$k^{\frac 1a} \cdot k^{\frac 1b} = k^{\frac 1c}$$

$$k^{\frac 1a + \frac 1b} = k^{\frac 1c}$$

$$\frac 1a + \frac 1b = \frac 1c$$

$$\frac 1c = \frac 1a + \frac 1b$$

$$\frac 1c = \frac {a+b}{ab}$$

$$c = \frac {ab}{a+b}$$

Answer (score 0):

From $3^a=15^c$ we get:

$a \ln (3)=c \ln (15)$.

Your turn !